# CurrentUICulture not persisted from OwnMiddleware

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, globalization

I'm trying to create an OwinMiddleware module that's role in life is to set the `CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` from an authenticated user's claim value.

I can get the claim value from the identity, but the `CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` is not being persisted into either the Controller or the Razor view.

The web application is hosted in IIS ( or IISExpress in dev boxes ).

Have I missed something fundamental ?

[EDIT] Added Startup class as per request.  I am using the default MVC5 template, with the `OwinStartupAttribute` attribute applied to the assembly.

- Microsoft.Owin: 3.0.1.0
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb: 3.0.1.0
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core: 2.0.0.0
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin: 2.0.0.0

---

```
public class GlobalisationMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    private string claimType;

    public GlobalisationMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, string claimType) : base(next)
    {
        this.claimType = claimType;
    }

    private bool IsTargetClaim(Claim claim)
    {
        return claim.Type == this.claimType;
    }

    public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        var user = context.Authentication.User;

        if (user != null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated && user.HasClaim(IsTargetClaim))
        {
            var userCulture = user.FindFirst(IsTargetClaim);

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(userCulture.Value);
        }

        await this.Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}

public static class GlobalisationMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IAppBuilder UseClaimsBasedGlobalisation(this IAppBuilder app, string claimType)
    {
        if (app == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("app");
        }

        app.Use<GlobalisationMiddleware>(claimType);
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.PostAuthorize);

        return app;
    }
}

[
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseClaimsBasedGlobalisation(NRI.Web.Framework.Security.CustomClaimTypes.Culture);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your OWIN startup file? i.e. where you call `app.UseClaimsBasedGlobalisation`. Can you also confirm that you are hitting `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(userCulture.Value);` with a breakpoint?

Comment: Done... from default MVC5 template with default comments removed for clarity.  The argument is a URI string

Comment: Yes, I can confirm the breakpoint is hit, and the culture is set to the appropriate value, at least inside my middleware instance

Comment: Ok was looking to see if you were being tripped up by your stage markers. But you're good. Next thing would be to confirm the threads are the same i.e. is the thread on which you set the culture the same thread / synchro context being used to run the controller etc. Put another way there is nothing wrong with what you have presented. I've run it here sans your custom claim type and it works just fine. So i very much doubt the problem is steering us in the face re: the code you have presented. My guess is a conflict / overwrite elsewhere in the call chain.

Comment: I've checked the managed thread ID's, they are the same in all parts of the code I've debugged into, including the controller's action

Comment: I added another Middleware component that executes first in the pipeline.  In there I set the CurrentUICulture before calling await Next.Invoke.  In my "real" middleware the CurrentUICulture is reset BACK to the original culture when the Invoke fn executes.  When my first middleware gets control back after "awaiting" the remaining pipeline the CurrentUICulture is reverted BACK to the value that was set earlier.  It appears each OWIN middleware invocation gets its own execution context and the synchronisation context is ignored

Comment: Are you using .NET 4.0 or 4.5? In 4.0 you have to self manage syncrocontext. In 4.5 this is done for you. http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2012/04/tpl-and-servers-pt2.html

Comment: Using .NET 4.6, appears to be using the AspNetSynchronizationContext